# Inserting/Deleting Exception using Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

While this is not a fault/error its coming up as an exception. When I try to delete or insert an object using core data, the first insert or delete shows the following error:

> 2012-04-09 18:57:32.201 SEA[7437:fb03] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1046
>   2012-04-09 18:57:32.203 SEA[7437:fb03] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

I am a bit unsure why this is coming up as the actual tableView shows the new row or deleted row. The database also shows the correct values and everything. 
The code I am using is the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
    }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [[[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }
```

Let me know if you need to see more code.

In the tableViewController that displays all the users. I have the following:

```
(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Here is the code for commitEditingStyle

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

    // Get context and user to delete
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    User *userToDelete = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Delete user from context
    [context deleteObject:userToDelete];

    // Save!
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![context save:&error]){
        // Handle the error..
    }

}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
  }   
}
```

Comment: Are you doing [tableview beginUpdates] in controllerWillChangeContent: and not [tableView endUpdates] in controllerDidChangeContent:?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect both those methods.

Comment: what are you doing in your tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: This usually happens when you modify the table view before updating the NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: I added the method you wanted to see.

Comment: How are you adding/deleting rows?

Comment: For deleting I tried using         [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; but it just crashes the app.

Comment: Have you implemented NSFetchResultsController's 
controller: didChangeObject: atIndexPath: forChangeType: newIndexPath: